# cheerio / jquery selectors: how to get a list of elements in nested div's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I need to parse some markup similar to this one, from an html page:

```
<div id="list">

  <div class="item-level-a">
    <div class="item-level-b">
      <a href="http://www.example.com/1"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-level-a">
    <div class="item-level-b">
      <a href="http://www.example.com/2"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-level-a">
    <div class="item-level-b">
      <a href="http://www.example.com/3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I did try with this code:

```
$list = [];
$('div[id="list"]').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).find('div > div > a').attribs('href');
  list.push(href);
});
```

without success: error was:

```
TypeError: Object <a href="http://www.example.com/1"></a>
                  <a href="http://www.example.com/2"></a>
                  <a href="http://www.example.com/3"></a>
has no method 'attribs'
```

:-(.

Any clue?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In `cheerio` and `jquery`, you get attributes with `attr()`, not `attrib()`.

There are a few other problems with your code. Here is a working version using `cheerio`. It probably works in `jquery` this way as well.:

```
var list = [];
$('div[id="list"]').find('div > div > a').each(function (index, element) {
  list.push($(element).attr('href'));
});
console.dir(list);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, it works like a charm (I'm feeling quite dumb right now... :-()

Comment: Feel good about your question! It provides all the relevant information one would want to solve your problem without overwhelming with a lot of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Thank you @Trott, I have been trying to target html elements for a while and your example help me a lot :)

Answer (score 18):

For those who prefer a functional style:

```js
const list = $('div[id="list"]')
  .find('div > div > a')
  .toArray()
  .map(element => $(element).attr('href')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Spread syntax also works for getting out of jQuery-style iteration functions:

```
const hrefs = [...$("div#list div > div > a")].map(e => $(e).attr("href"));
```

There's no need for the extra `.find()` call since querying ancestors deeply is supported in a single CSS selector.