# cheerio equivalent query to select the nth div inside the main div

Tags: node.js, xpath, cheerio

I am trying to get the list of elements inside a particular div as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655287/2481350). However the element I am trying to find doesnt have any attributes but can be located using the following xpath `//*[@id="main"]/div[4]/div`.

I tried using `$('div[id="main"]/div[4]/div')`. but it doesnot work. any suggestions?

example code below:-

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require("fs");

const body = fs.readFileSync("check.html");
const $ = cheerio.load(body);


var list = [];
$('div[id="main"]').find('div > a').each(function (index, element) {
  list.push($(element).attr('href'));
});



console.dir(list.length);
```

In the example above is getting everything from inside `div#main` so the number of elements with `a` tags is much larger than the targeted div by the xpath. what should be the cheerio equivalent query?

Answer (score 2):

convert xpath to css. target fourth child div and all its div's ahref children right away:

```
$('div[id="main"] > div:nth-of-type(4) > div > a').each(function (index, element) {
    list.push($(element).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: My xpath is rusty but I think the more equivalent css is `nth-of-type`

Comment: @pguardiario correct, it should be `nth-of-type`, thanks